Migrating from 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client' to Modern Database Solutions in MAUI
I am currently migrating one of my xamarin forms apps to MAUI and need to replace the outdated 'MicroSoft.Azure.Mobile.Client' package, which I used to connect my app to my database. Previously, I managed the connection with the following code:
static UserManager defaultInstance = new UserManager(); //instance of the user manager
        MobileServiceClient client; //instance of app service client to talk to Azure
        IMobileServiceTable<User> userTable; //instance of user table



this.client = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.ApplicationURL, new HttpClientHandler()); //sets the app service URL
          this.userTable = client.GetTable<User>(); //gets the user table from the app service instance.


What is the best approach to handle database connections in MAUI, given that this package is no longer supported? Are there any alternatives or packages that can perform similar functions in MAUI?
Any advice or direction would be most appreciated.

Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client is not a database connection library...
